# SQL Server ROW_NUMBER Left Join + when you don't know column names

Tags: sql, sql-server, left-join, row-number

I'm writing a page that will create a query (for non-db users) and it create the query and run it returning the results for them.

I am using `row_number` to handle custom pagination.

How do I do a left join and a `row_number` in a subquery when I don't know the specific columns I need to return. I tried to use `*` but I get an error that

> The column '' was specified multiple times

Here is the query I tried:

```
SELECT * FROM 
  (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Test) AS ROW_NUMBER, *
   FROM table1 a
   LEFT JOIN table2 b 
   ON a.ID = b.ID) x
WHERE ROW_NUMBER BETWEEN 1 AND 50
```

Comment: try a.*, b.* instead of *. should work.

Comment: That did not work. I wonder if SQL Server 2005 is my issue. I'm trying to test the query using Microsoft SQL Server manamgent studio.

Comment: You need to write or dynamically generate a query that lists the specific columns and that does not include the same column name twice.

Comment: @MartinSmith - Is there a way to include that query that returns the specific columns names in that sql or would it be a separate query AND I would have to figure out how to include the table name in the column like Table1.fieldone, Table2.fieldtwo

Answer (score 0):

Your query is going to fail in SQL Server regardless of the `row_number()` call.  The `*` returns all columns, including `a.id` and `b.id`.  These both have the same name.  This is fine for a query, but for a subquery, all columns need distinct names.

You can use `row_number()` for an arbitrary ordering by using a "subquery with constant" in the `order by` clause:

```
SELECT * FROM 
  (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (select NULL)) AS ROW_NUMBER, *
   FROM table1 a
   LEFT JOIN table2 b 
   ON a.ID = b.ID) x
WHERE ROW_NUMBER BETWEEN 1 AND 50 ;
```

This removes the dependency on the underlying column name (assuming none are named ROW_NUMBER).

Answer (score 0):

Try this sql. It should work.

```
SELECT * FROM 
  (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY a.Test) AS ROW_NUMBER, a.*,b.*
   FROM table1 a
   LEFT JOIN table2 b 
   ON a.ID = b.ID) x
WHERE ROW_NUMBER BETWEEN 1 AND 50
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, I still get the error about the column being specific multiple times. I am using SQL Server 2005. Does that changed anything?

Comment: @htkhtk : can you please change order by Test to either order by a.Test or order by b.Test. May be that is the problem.